# Date (Month/Year) Based on Number in another Column

Tags: date, powerbi

I have a column in powerbi that repeats the numbers 1-12, and I would like another column to display a date (month and year) based on that number, such that 1 always corresponds to the current month/year, two would be next month, etc. like this:

Index | Date
1     | July 2022
2     | August 2022
3     | September 2022

and on August 1, it would change to:

Index | Date
1     | August 2022
2     | September 2022
3     | October 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula in a **calculated column**:

```
Date 1 = 
FORMAT( 
    DATE( 
        YEAR(NOW()), 
        MONTH(NOW()) + 'Table'[Index], 
        1
    ), 
    "mmmm yyyy"
)
```